# Porting C wrappers for JNI, from Windows to Linux

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Being a JAVA developer (with limited knowledge in C), I have to get working the SDK for a imaging device on Linux.

Here is the scenario. The device SDK have shared libraries implemented on Windows (.dll) and Linux (.so). The name and signature of the functions in both implementations are the same, even there is one only reference manual for both.

They provide some Java code that calls native methods by using JNI. As the functions in the SDK libraries can't be called directly by JNI, there is a C code provided too with the SDK, that exposes the functions in the way they can be called by JNI (it's basically the implementation of the header generated with "javah" tool).

Now my problem is that this C code that exposes the JNI-like functions is provided by the vendor tested and compiled on Windows, so I have to compile in Linux and in the process, making the change of what is the necessary.

At this point, I have executed the follow gcc command:

gcc -shared -o some.so some.c -I/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_40/include    -I/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_40/include/linux     -I/someSDKpath/Linux/Inc

the compiler throws this error:

> /someSDKpath/Linux/Inc/bioapi_type.h:195: error: expected ‘)’ before
>   ‘*’ token

This line refers to:

```
typedef BioAPI_RETURN (BioAPI *BioAPI_ModuleEventHandler)
    (const BioAPI_UUID *BSPUuid,
    void* AppNotifyCallbackCtx,
    BioAPI_DEVICE_ID DeviceID,
    uint32 Reserved,
    BioAPI_MODULE_EVENT EventType);
```

And the error happens each time a type of this kind is declared.

I hope that some one can help me with this error or give me some guidelines to success with this work.

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Thanks to [Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318758/joni) I could resolve the former problem.

Now I have one (repetitive) error more:

> PvsApiJv.c:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’
>   before ‘mBioAPI_ModuleLoad’

This kind of error, is generated in every line when one of the following cases is present:

```
static BOOL                         mBioAPI_ModuleLoad;
```

Can I change it to "int" and find the usages to replace 0 instead of False and 1 instead of True?
:::

```
INT                                 mRegistScore = 0;
```

I don't know why they use "INT" besides "int" for other variables. How can I proceed with this?
:::

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) BioAPI_RETURN BioAPI BioAPI_ModuleUnload();
```

Should I use "IMPORT" or "**attribute**((dllexport))"?. Searching I found a few recomendations but I am not sure what would be the one to apply.
:::

```
CRITICAL_SECTION                    mGuiStateCS;
```

This last one I know is a specific Windows type. What equivalent could I use as replace?

Comment: Is the compiling command you are using correct? Does it have a manual telling how to compile it on Linux?

Comment: Hi TwoCode. Actually the vendor does not provide official support for this code on Linux. They only say in their support web site FAQ, that for Linux wrapper, one must refer to the Windows code as guide. I tailored the used command, after read a brief tutorial about compiling dinamyc libraries on Linux.

Comment: A quick google search gave me https://code.google.com/p/jbioapi/ which might help. I would suggest not anonymizing the sdk you need (it might help if someone already did the job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [header file in question](http://code.google.com/p/jbioapi/source/browse/trunk/src/bioapi_type.h) does not define the `BioAPI` macro on Linux because it assumes that the macro `UNIX` is defined if the program is not being compiled on Windows. This means that the compiler will see an invalid function pointer declaration, which causes the error.

```
 20 #elif defined (UNIX)
 21 
 22 #define BioAPI
 23 #define CALLBACK
 24 
 25 #endif
```

You can define the macro at compile time, on the compiler's command line:

```
gcc -DUNIX -shared -o some.so some.c ....
```